# Can someone try answering this question?

Tags: discussion

[Is "blue scorpion venom" a legitimate treatment for cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8761/is-blue-scorpion-venom-a-legitimate-treatment-for-cancer)

I was going to try, but the amount of information and lack of understanding about most of this stuff was too much for me. I found way too much conflicting information and quite frankly, I'm not clever enough to debunk/prove this by myself. These links may be of use to anyone who tries to answer:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5359575/ - This study shows that a sister drug "Vidatox" actually proliferates liver cancer cell growth

http://www.escozul-cancer.com/

I would put all my rep as a bounty on this question but I don't know how or if I can.

Comment: Gave it a shot.  Unfortunately it's a really complex issue since there're all sorts of types of cancer, patients, and ways to derive alleged remedies from blue scorpion venom, so there's not going to be a single, easy answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have links to information that you think will help someone answer, please post it as a comment. (But be careful of posting "pseudo-answers". We are looking for real answers that can be edited, voted upon and accepted.)

If you want to encourage people to answer, bounties are the right way. You have enough rep to do this (well, once!) [Here's how to do it.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

Comment: Another thought: This is a 2012 question about a 2003 claim. It isn't clear that anyone still believes this. If you can find a *notable* source from 2017 that makes it clear belief in this claim is still widespread, edit it into the question. Not only will it bump back to the front page, but it may convince people it is worth the effort to investigate.